# Kafka Streams Word Count How Does it Work?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having difficulty understanding the basic kafka stream example:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java

```
// Construct a `KStream` from the input topic "streams-plaintext-input", where message values
// represent lines of text (for the sake of this example, we ignore whatever may be stored
// in the message keys).  The default key and value serdes will be used.
final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(inputTopic);

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

final KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
  // Split each text line, by whitespace, into words.  The text lines are the record
  // values, i.e. we can ignore whatever data is in the record keys and thus invoke
  // `flatMapValues()` instead of the more generic `flatMap()`.
  .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(pattern.split(value.toLowerCase())))
  // Group the split data by word so that we can subsequently count the occurrences per word.
  // This step re-keys (re-partitions) the input data, with the new record key being the words.
  // Note: No need to specify explicit serdes because the resulting key and value types
  // (String and String) match the application's default serdes.
  .groupBy((keyIgnored, word) -> word)
  // Count the occurrences of each word (record key).
  .count();

// Write the `KTable<String, Long>` to the output topic.
wordCounts.toStream().to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Can someone please explain the .flatMapValues part?

From what I can see, flatMapValues turn the `KStream<String, String>` to 
`KStream<String, List<String>>` so how does the subsequent .groupBy chained can somehow have `String, String` input params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.flatMap` is an operator that, when returned a collection, will return its individual elements "flattened" out into individual items to the next operator

Comment: String[][] data = new String[][]{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}};

//Stream<String[]>
Stream<String[]> temp = Arrays.stream(data);

//Stream<String>, GOOD!
Stream<String> stringStream = temp.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x));

But dont you need to do something like this in order to flat out the collection, instead of returning a list?

Comment: @user1955934, Check signature of `KStream::flatMapValues`, passed function has to return `Iterable`

Comment: ok i think java 8 stream 's flatMap does not work the same way as KStream's flatMapValues.. I think i made a wrong assumption.